# Pointers giving different results in printf

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning some C and I am testing simple pointer things so that I can comprehend them more.
I think I don't get something right.
Given the simple code from below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    long n = 1;
    long *y = &n;
    n = 2;
    printf("n: %d\n",&n);
    printf("y: %d\n",y);
}
```

Results are:

```
n: 6422296
y: 6422296
```

Which is the position in memory I guess.

If I change the print lines to:

```
printf("n: %d\n",&n);
printf("y: %d\n",&y);
```

Results are:

```
n: 6422300
y: 6422296
```

I guess `n` is stored 4 bytes after `y` in memory but don't get why. I am not changing `n` in the output and I am leaving the `&` in however the output value changes when adding the `&` to the `y`.

If I leave it like so:

```
printf("n: %d\n",n);
printf("y: %d\n",&y);
```

The output is:

```
n: 2
y: 6422296
```

This result is one I was expecting.

Why this behaviour?
There is something I'm missing.

Don't be rude. I read tutorials and explanations on pointers but nothing explains these for me.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are invoking *undefined behavior* because `%d` is not the correct specifier for pointers, it's `%p`

Comment: *"I guess n is stored 4 bytes after y in memory but don't get why"* - because the compiler decide to store them like that. There isn't really any "better" reason, unless you want to get into how compilers are implemented (which I doubt will help you much at the current stage of learning)

Comment: "I guess n is stored 4 bytes after y in memory but don't get why."  What were you expecting?  That they would be in a different order, with `y` after `n`? The compiler can put anything anywhere it wants, but more importantly, it shouldn't matter to you or your program.

Comment: `y` and `&y` are different things. `y` is a pointer that stores the address of `n`. Note that `y` is also a variable on its own, so it has an address in the memory which is represented by `&y`. So, `&y` is the address of the `y`. So, normally, `&y` and `y` will be different.

Comment: @TruthSeeker: It seems that you overwrote my changes in your most recent edit. You probably started editing before I applied my edit, i.e. we were both editing at the same time. I have therefore reverted your edit, because, as far as I can tell, my edit was more comprehensive. However, feel free to apply another edit to the question, using the most recent revision as the foundation of the edit.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: yes, my edit was pretty much same no issue with reverting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question comes down to "why does the address of `n` change when I add a print of the address of `y`".  The answer to which comes down to the details of how compilers and optimizers work and how they allocate storage for things.

When you declare a variable local to a function like this, the compiler has a lot of freedom for how to deal with it.  It may allocate space in the stack frame it creates for the function, or it may keep the variable in a register, or it may do both, or it may even do something else.  The only requirement is that it ends up producing code that matches the execution semantics of the program.

In case of local variables like this, if they never have their address taken (as is the case with `y`), then a good compiler will usually try to keep the variable in a register and never allocate memory for it.  So in the first program it only needs space for one variable (`n`) in the stack frame (`n` has its address taken so must reside in memory to have an address).

In the second program, both `y` and `n` have their addresses taken, so both must be in memory.  It so happens that the compiler decides to place `y` at the lower address and `n` at a larger address, but there is no guarentee of that.  There's also no requirement that they be "next to" each other in any sense.

Answer (score 1):

`y` gives you the value, which is the address of `n`.

`&y` gives you the address of `y`, regardless of what type `y` is.

- `&` is the address operator.  It gives you the address of the variable.
- `*` when used in expressions, is the dereference operator.  It gives you the value to which a pointer points.  In your example `*y` would give you the value of `n`.
- `*` when used in a declaration (e.g. your `long *y`) specifies that the variable will hold an address/pointer.

To learn and understand C, it helps to read the appropriate sections of the famous [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 0):

`n` is a long, `y` is a pointer to `long`. Both take up their own memory

I modified your code very slightly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    long n = 1;
    long *y = &n;
    n = 2;
    printf("&n: %p\n",&n); //Please change format specifier to %p for pointer
    printf("y: %p\n",y);
}
```

In the first `printf()` call you are printing the address of `n`, in the second `printf()` call you are printing the value stored in `y`. Since you initialized `y` with the address of `n`, these must be the same.

In your next set of `printf()`s (again slightly modified):

```
printf("n: %ld\n",n); //Please change format specifier to %ld for long int
printf("&y: %p\n",&y); //This one is still a pointer though (long**)
```

You are printing the value of `n` and the address of `y`.

The first `printf()` must print `2` because it is the most recent value stored in `n`. The second `printf()` is going to print the address of `y`, which is the memory address where the address of `n` is stored. `&y` is a pointer to a pointer to a long.

```
printf("&y: %p\n",&y);
```

can never print the address of `n` because `y` and `n` are stored in different memory locations